# Need to add a item to a list drop down from a workerthread

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to change a c# label from a background thread.

However, I need to add an item to a dropdown list.  how would I modify my method for adding an item to the list?

```
   private void running(string s)
        {
            if (label44.InvokeRequired)
            {
                stringDelegate sd = new stringDelegate(running);
                this.Invoke(sd, new object[] { s });
            }
            else
            {
                label44.Text = "Running Lit Report";

            }
        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Same way you would without a worker thread, just add the code after setting label44.Text...

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work.

```
private void running(string s)
{
    var action = (ListBox lb, string s) => lb.Add(s);
    if (myListBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(action, new object[]{myListBox, s});
    }
    else
    {
        action(myListBox, s);
    }
}
```